# Find all real solution for k: $2\sin^2(x)+6\cos^2\left(\frac x4\right)=5-2k$

Tags: trigonometry

I have been stuck at this problem for some time now. I'd really apprechiate your help. Thanks.

$$2\sin^2(x)+6\cos^2(\frac x4)=5-2k$$

Comment: All unsuccesful

Comment: What is $k{}{}{}{}?$

Comment: You have to find all the real numbers for k so that it makes the equation real

Comment: What do we have to find exactly? The values for $k$ for which the equation has a real root? Or do we have to find the actual solutions? Please, clarify.

Comment: Note that $\cos 2y = 2\cos^2 y-1$ and $\sin^2 2z = 4 \sin^2z \cos^2 z=4(1-\cos^2 z)(\cos^2 z)$. Use this to express things in terms of $\cos \frac x2$

Comment: "All unsuccessful"  What are?  In what way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:* The problem is about finding the minimum and maximum values of $
2\sin^2(x)+6\cos^2\left(\frac x4\right)$.

The minimum value is easy: it's $0$, taken at $x=10\pi$ for instance.

The maximum value is [not easy](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=max+2sin%5E2%28x%29%2B6cos%5E2%28x%2F4%29): it's approximately $M=7.24701$.

This gives $0 \le 5-2k \le M$, or $(5 - M)/2 \le k \le 5/2$.

Comment: Note that $M=4a^2+\frac 94a+3$ where
$$a=\sqrt{\frac 23}\cos\left(\frac 13\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{9}{16}\sqrt{\frac 32}\right)\right) $$

Comment: @bjorn93, how did you find this? Perhaps you can add your answer with that result.

Comment: @bjorn93. My apologies for not having paid attention to your comment. As lhf commented, it would be nice you post an answer leading to this solution.

Answer (score 1):

*Too long for a comment but I cannot resist when I see an equation !*

As @lhf answered, we are looking for the maximum of
$$f(x)=2 \sin ^2(x)+6 \cos ^2\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)$$ so for the zero's of
$$f'(x)=2 \sin (2 x)-\frac{3}{2} \sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$$
Let $x=2 \sin ^{-1}(t)$ to get as a new equation
$$8 t \left(1-2 t^2\right) \sqrt{1-t^2}-\frac{3 t}{2}=0$$ Discarding the trivial $t=0$ and squaring
$$1024 t^6-2048 t^4+1280 t^2-247=0$$ which is a cubic in $t^2$ and, using $z=t^2$, the solutions are given by
$$z_k=\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3} \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi  k}{3}-\frac{1}{3} \cos
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{13}{256}\right)\right) \qquad \text{with} \qquad k=0,1,2$$ Back to $t$ and $x$, the final solution is
$$x_*=2 \sin ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}-\frac{1}{3} \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{6}+\frac{1}{3} \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{13}{256}\right)\right)}\right)\approx 1.33019$$ and then
$$f(x_*)=4+\sqrt{3\left(1+\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{6}+\frac{1}{3} \sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{13}{256}\right)\right) \right) }+$$ $$\cos \left(2 \sin ^{-1}\left(-\frac 13+\frac 23\sin \left(\frac{\pi }{6}+\frac{1}{3} \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{13}{256}\right)\right)\right)\right)\approx 7.24701$$

**Edit**

This is exactly the same result as the elegant one provided by @bjorn93 (which, I must confess, I did  not pay attention when I started working the problem).

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

If you are trying to solve for $k$ in terms of $x$, why not use the fact that $\sin^2 a + \cos^2 a = 1$ for all real $a$, and eliminate $\sin^2$ on the LHS, and then use $\arccos$ to do what you need?

Comment: How can I expres $$cos^2(\frac x4)$$ as $$cos^2(x)$$

Comment: @vlonjatiii why do you need to? $\cos^2(x/4) = a \iff x = 4 \arccos(\pm \sqrt{a})$